# Bootstrap 4 table cell vertical align doesn't seem to be working as the docs suggest

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm not able to get Bootstrap 4 to vertically align the word "top" at the top of a table data cell. The documentation seems pretty clear/simple. They recommend align-text-top for tables and for spans they recommend align-top. Neither works in my example below. When I look in the developer toolbar, vertical-aign: top is applied by the table class definition in Bootstrap, but it is not honored by the browser (Chrome) in this case. What am I missing?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="w-50">Something</th>
        <th class="w-50"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="line-height: 40px;">
        <td><span class="align-top">top</span> </td>
        <td class="align-text-top">top </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contact (if other than owner): </td>
        <td>Contact (if other than operator): </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mailing Address: </td>
        <td>Mailing Address: </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City, State, Zip: </td>
        <td>City, State, Zip: </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap table cells are top-aligned by default. (Inspecting a `td` in the developer tools will confirm this.) These table cells appear middle-aligned only because the text is too short to trigger the word wrap. If you give any one of those cells enough text to wrap onto a second line, the text in the adjacent cell will stay near the top as the row height increases.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
       magna aliqua.
    </td>
    <td>Top</td>
</tr>
```

But if you'd just like to position the text higher in the cell regardless of text length, you can give any `td` utility classes like `pt-0 pb-3` to override Bootstrap's default padding of .75rem.